# Android Launcher displays Tab Activities

Tags: android, tabs

I have an Android App that uses TabWidgets for displaying 4 Tabs. Each Tab opens an Activity. All is working fine. Now I open the Launcher and what I see are all my Tabs are also Apps. I have "POI","Routes","Map","E-Bike" as Tabs and all the four are also in the Launcher beyond the real App.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have below intent filter in each of your activity declaration in Manifest. 
Have this in only those activities that need to be shown on Launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanx very much. I nearly want to do suicide ;)